# Haskell Equality Constraint

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, haskell, yesod

I'm trying to build bootstrap 3 compatibility for Yesod. However, doing so by making a "renderBootstrap3" function is impossible because you can't add class to inputs. So, I've opted for making bootstrap versions of the fields in `Form.Fields`. The idea is that I can clone the normal fields but add a class declaration in the attributes array. Here is the relevant code:

```
import qualified Yesod.Form.Fields as F

injectClass :: (Text -> Text -> [(Text,Text)] -> Either Text a -> Bool -> WidgetT (HandlerSite m) IO ()
           Text -> Text -> [(Text,Text)] -> Either Text a -> Bool -> WidgetT (HandlerSite m) IO ()
injectClass f a b attrs d e = f a b attrs d e

textField :: (Monad m, RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage) => Field m Text
textField = addInputClass F.textField

addInputClass :: (Monad m, RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage) => Field m a -> Field m a
addInputClass f = f { fieldView = (injectClass $ fieldView f)}
```

So, my intention is to take the normal version of text field and use record syntax to modify only the fieldView method. This method should be replaced by a one that is identical except for the addition of a class attribute. This is not yet implemented in the code above. It would probably look something like:

```
injectClass f a b attrs d e = f a b (("class", "form-control") : attrs) d e
```

Anyway, the problem is that the original code won't compile. I get an equality constraint error:

```
Could not deduce (HandlerSite m0 ~ HandlerSite m)
from the context (Monad m,
                  RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage)
  bound by the type signature for
             addInputClass :: (Monad m,
                               RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage) =>
                              Field m a -> Field m a
  at Field/Bootstrap.hs:27:18-95
NB: `HandlerSite' is a type function, and may not be injective
The type variable `m0' is ambiguous
Possible fix: add a type signature that fixes these type variable(s)
Expected type: FieldViewFunc m a
  Actual type: Text
               -> Text
               -> [(Text, Text)]
               -> Either Text a
               -> Bool
               -> WidgetT (HandlerSite m0) IO ()
In the `fieldView' field of a record
In the expression: f {fieldView = (injectClass $ fieldView f)}
In an equation for `addInputClass':
    addInputClass f = f {fieldView = (injectClass $ fieldView f)}
```

Notice that `FieldViewFunc m a` is defined as

```
type FieldViewFunc m a
    = Text -- ^ ID
   -> Text -- ^ Name
   -> [(Text, Text)] -- ^ Attributes
   -> Either Text a -- ^ Either (invalid text) or (legitimate result)
   -> Bool -- ^ Required?
   -> WidgetT (HandlerSite m) IO ()
```

So, I'm not far off. The problem is (I think) that it isn't recoginizing that `injectClass` doesn't change the monad. However, this should be obvious to the compiler. The type signature for `injectClass` is clear about this. I'm looking for what I need to do to satisfy GHC. Thanks for any help, and let me know if I can be more clear.

Comment: Can you try this type signature : `addInputClass :: forall m a. (Monad m, RenderMessage (HandlerSite m) FormMessage) => Field m a -> Field m a 
`. Using language extension: `{-# LANGUAGE ScopedTypeVariables #-}`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, type families and non-injectivity.

Here's what's going on: we are trying to type-check

```
f { fieldView = (injectClass $ fieldView f)}
```

The problem is not that `injectClass` might change what `m` is. The problem is that it doesn't *know* what `m` is. Its input, `fieldView f` and context, setting the `fieldView` field of `f`, both only tell it what `HandlerSite m` is, and the simple fact is you can't work out what `m` is from there. It's like if you had the following:

```
type family F a
type instance F Int = Bool
type instance F Char = Bool
```

Now trying to pass an `F Int` where an `F Char` is expected will succeed, because they're both just `Bool`. Hence, trying to pass a `HandlerSite m0` where a `HandlerSite m` is expected might succeed, even if `m` is not `m0`! Hence, the type checker can't be sure that `m0` is supposed to be the same as `m`, so you get an ambiguous type error.

Moreover, you *can't* easily resolve the ambiguity with manual annotations, since you'll run into the same problem: you'll be telling the type checker what `HandlerSite m` should be, which it already knows.

Can you remove `HandlerSite m` from the type signature of `injectClass` entirely, replacing it with just an ordinary type variable `h`, say? That ought to solve your problem, but I'm not sure if it will create any new ones.

Answer (score 0):

There is an easier solution. You could redefine `areq` and `aopt` to automatically add necessary classes:

```
areqBs3 :: (RenderMessage site FormMessage, HandlerSite m ~ site, MonadHandler m)
     => Field m a
     -> FieldSettings site
     -> Maybe a
     -> AForm m a
areqBs3 a b = areq a (b {fsAttrs = [("class", "form-control")]})
```